# Using GPU in vanilla JS without GPU.js, WebGL or Three.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, 3d, ctx

I 'am trying to make 3d engine, but is lagging as hell. The reason is 2073600 pixels for ctx to draw.
Is here any possible way to use GPU without GPU.js, WebGL or Three.js?

I tried so hard but not gone so far with GPU.js, because it didn't work:

> "GPU is not a constructor".
> I hope that there exist method to use GPU in vanilla JS.

Thanks for reading, and have a good day.

Comment: so, you don't want to use `GPU.js` or you don't know how to use `GPU.js`?

Comment: @JaromandaX XI added him to my project but he can't somehow initialize GPU class or something.

Comment: then you did it wrong - just add `<script src="https://unpkg.com/gpu.js@latest/dist/gpu-browser.min.js"></script>` as per documentation to the head of your web page

Comment: https://imgur.com/BRn3dML and https://imgur.com/gNu2Bsk

Comment: IDK maybe i'm just cursed

Comment: do you see an error [here](https://jsfiddle.net/a2s6Ln7b/)

Comment: "<a class='gotoLine' href='#38:17'>38:17</a> Uncaught TypeError: GPU is not a constructor"

Comment: I think it can be problem with my chrome.

Comment: what the heck is `<a class='gotoLine' href='#38:17'>38:17</a>`??? nothing to do with the jsfiddle link I posted

Comment: Check your browser developer tools network tab - does `https://unpkg.com/gpu.js@latest/dist/gpu-browser.min.js` load?

Comment: @JaromandaX yup https://imgur.com/c1P9eVW

Comment: the red bit makes me believe otherwise

Comment: Is your code hosted locally (files on your computer), or are you hosting them on a remote server? If you're hosting the files locally, you might be running into CORS issues. What do you see when you tick / check the Blocked requests checkbox in the Network tab of your browser's developer tools?